# Azure pipeline "each" expression only in certain task

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I know I can use each expressions in yaml pipelines. Like this:

```
parameters:
- name: domains
  type: object
  default:
  - domain1.domain.com
  - domain2.domain.com

steps:
- ${{ each domain in parameters.domains }}:
  - task: Bash@3
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: 'echo ${{ domain }}'
```

How can I use the each expression for only one single task or stage? I tried with:

```
parameters:
- name: domains
  type: object
  default:
  - domain1.domain.com
  - domain2.domain.com

stages:
- stage: 1
  jobs:
  - job:
    steps:
    - ${{ each domain in parameters.domains }}:
    - checkout: none
    - task: Bash@3
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          echo "This should run for each value in ${{ domain }}"

- stage: 2
  jobs:
  - job:
    steps:
    - checkout: none
    - task: Bash@3
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          echo "This should only run once"
```

And the pipeline won't run. It has an error:

```
Encountered error(s) while parsing pipeline YAML:
/azure-pipelines-1.yml: (Line: 13, Col: 1, Idx: 148) - (Line: 13, Col: 2, Idx: 149): While scanning for the next token, find character that cannot start any token.
```

If this can't work I'll just use a bash loop, but I would really want to use the parameters at run time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not only you need to indent steps after the expression, also you should not name the stage name start with a number as well as the “checkout: none” task is not allowed to be used multiple times in a job. See: [Template types & usage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops) for details.

Therefore,  below format should work as expected:

```
parameters:
- name: domains
  type: object
  default:
  - domain1.domain.com
  - domain2.domain.com


stages:
- stage: stage1
  jobs:
  - job: 
    steps:
    - checkout: none
    - ${{ each domain in parameters.domains }}:
      - task: Bash@3
        inputs:
          targetType: 'inline'
          script: 'echo ${{ domain }}'
    - task: Bash@3
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          echo "This should only run once"

- stage: stage2
  jobs:
  - job:
    steps:
    - checkout: none
    - task: Bash@3
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          echo "This should only run once"
```

Comment: Great, thanks. Didn't know you can have multiple checkout none.

Comment: How can I use the each expression for only one particular task in the same stage?

Comment: I have updated my answer for your reference.

Answer (score 2):

you need to indent steps after the expression:

```
    - ${{ each domain in parameters.domains }}:
      - checkout: none
      - task: Bash@3
        inputs:
          targetType: 'inline'
          script: |
            echo "This should run for each value in ${{ domain }}"
```